# Entity Framework Migration Automatic Seeding

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I am trying to migrate from the old SQL Server CE and winforms to Entity Framework code-first Migration as this is the new approach I have taken for the past 1 and half year now.

My question is: I have created a Winforms that uses Entity Framework and migrations seeding.

And this program has a log in user table. There for, every time the code run at first time for the machine, will it also run the migration seeding by default?

In MVC or any Web Server that supports this, will call the automatic migration seeding by default, if not then we can configure it on the migrations configuration for example. `OnModelCreating` and then `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`

Now since we are not running on an ASP Server. But only local, will it also run the seeding as I plan to add an default user account when the application is run the first time. Instead of calling an `AddOrUpdate` function inside the forms class instead.

I am not sure if this works on my end properly, because I am forced to use `Update-Database`, which will also run a pending seed for the migration.

So there is no way for me to confirm it. Unless I send my file to a neighbor and tell them to install .Net framework 4.0 and SQL Server.

Comment: Not sure I understand your issue. The migration seeding will run when the app model doesn't match the database it's connected to and you either have auto migrations on or do an update-database. If there is some seed code you don't want repeated, you can use the AddOrUpdate() as you mention or just enclose it an if statement (if record(s) don't exist, insert).

Comment: Yes, that is the very basic use and flow of the Migrations. My question is. Will this run automatically in Winforms. For example if I execute the myApplication.exe and assuming there is no Database set up yet, because it is the first use of the Application. Will the Seed run on the as well. I understand that in the Web hosting. After the deployment of an commit, it will run automatically. Now for .exe. will it do that as well?

Comment: Yes, since your initializer is MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion it will run when you first access the context or you can force it with context.Database.Initialize(true);